# Get the story board viewcontroller customview instance in another class(Like Singleton)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboard

In story board, we can add a custom view class for a particular view in the view controller.That custom class init by `-initWithCoder:`. we can add custom code within that method. When the view controller initilize that custom view also initilized through the above method. So the viewcontroller and the customview instantiated.

Now my question is, if i want to access the instance of those customview and viewcontroller which are already instantiated in another class(not the same view controller class), how can i get those instance(like singleton)?
is it possible to get those instance in anotherclass?

Answer (score 0):

thank you boss for more sensitive questions. all developers are seeming like this. congratulate to you bright future. by the by, we move to our issue. 
Open up ViewController.xib, and bring up the Assistant Editor so ViewController.h is visible. Control-drag from the text field down below the @interface to bring up the Connection popup. Set the Connection to Action, the name to sendTurn, and click Connect